# http.Handle not working in Golang

Tags: go

I try render a template:

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", index)
http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
err := fcgi.Serve(nil, http.HandlerFunc(handler))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
   t, _ := template.ParseFiles("404.html")
   t.Execute(w, &page{Title: "not work"})
}
```

But when I open every page, even site.com/login, I see 404.
Where can I find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fcgi package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/) explains

> [...] If handler [second argument of fcgi.Serve] is nil, http.DefaultServeMux is used.

In order to make use of functions registered with `http.HandleFunc` in `http.DefaultServeMux` you should not pass second argument to `Serve` function otherwise the handler function will serve all requests.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    err := fcgi.Serve(nil, nil)
}
```